# Asyncio how to run 10 concurrent functions forever

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

Question on asyncio. I have this working just not sure if it's the correct way or if there is a easier way.

The short versions of what I am trying to do is continuously to execute the run() 10x concurrently

To do this I had to create a function work_it() with a While True Loop

The run() function take about 5 minutes to complete. Database calls, processing, aiohttp reqeusts, and etc.

Is this the best way to to do this or is there another way to have asyncio continuously run a function over and over again with 10 concurrent processes.

Also is asyncio.gather the correct function to use? Am I better of using an executor?

Thanks in advance.

Erik

```
db = Database()
conn = db.connect()

async def run(worker_id=None):
   """
   Using Shared Database Conneciton
   Create a object. Query the database, process the data, and do a http post with aiohttp
   Returns: True\False based on the http post
   """
   # my_object = Object_Model(db)
   # await do_sql_queries
   # await process_data
   # Lots of processing
   # result = await aiohttp_requests
   
   nap_time = random.randint(1,5)
   print(f'Worker-{worker_id} sleeping for {nap_time}')
   await asyncio.sleep(nap_time)
   return True

async def work_it(worker_id=None):
    """
    This worker should run forever
    """
    while True:
        start = time.monotonic()
        result = await run(worker_id)
        duration = time.monotonic() - start
        print(f'Worker-{worker_id} ran for {duration:.6f} seconds')


async def main():
    """
    Start 10 "workers"
    """
    workers = 10
    tasks = []
    for worker_id in range(1, workers+1):
        print(f'Building Task {worker_id}')
        tasks.append(work_it(worker_id))

    print(f'Await Gather')
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: This is exactly the way to do it. An executor is for executing **sync** code in a thread or process.

Comment: Cool thanks, new to asyncio\coroutine. The executor comment was should I be breaking this out to it's own thread\process. Sorry was a little vague on it.

Comment: Asyncio is single-threaded by design (similar to JavaScript), although you can connect it to executors if needed. In general, async/await is for waiting in parallel, while threads and processes are for working in parallel. Since you don't have CPU-heavy code, you need async.